# How do I create an instance store based AMI from an EBS instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, amazon-ami

To give a background,

I need about 10 instance replicas for a research purpose. So, here is what i do:

1. I have an EBS based EC2 instance as master instance where i do all the development.
2. Create an AMI out of the master and launch 9 instances using it.
3. Whenever there is a change in master(Apart from code change, i manage code sync using SVN) i repeat the step 2.

As the master instance has EBS backed, the instances that i launch using its AMI also has the same.

Now, i dont want the other 9 instance to have EBS (for cost purpose).

So, my question is

1. Can i create a S3-backed / instance-store AMI out of an EBS based instance?
   [ or ]
2. Can i create S3-backed / instance-store instance from EBS based AMI?

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can i create a S3-backed /
>      instance-store AMI out of an EBS
>      based instance?

Yes, you can create an Instance-store AMI out of an EBS based instance.

1. Install ec2-ami-tools in the instance
2. Upload your x509 certificates to the instance
3. Use ec2-bundle-vol and ec2-upload-bundle commands
   NOTE: You need your account ID, Access Key and Secret Key to run these commands
4. Register the image specifying the bucket/manifest name where you have uploaded the image files.

Step by step documentation can be found at http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/2008-02-01/GettingStartedGuide/?ref=get-started
Refer the Creating an Image section of this guide.

> Can i create S3-backed /
>      instance-store instance from EBS
>      based AMI?

No you can't

Comment: Thank you very much vishnu. Will follow the above steps.

Comment: I had no problem with first 3 steps. But, when registering the image im getting the following error.

Client.InvalidManifest: Invalid block device mapping: Invalid virtual name 'ebs0'

Any idea?